# Set a column alias with Java PreparedStatements

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, prepared-statement

Hello all :) I want to name dynamically my columns with Oracle 10g. Here is what I would like to do:

```
SELECT 
  NAME as "User.Name",
  EMAIL as "User.Email.For.Criteria2.at." || CRITERIA 
FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE 
  CRITERIA = ?
```

Or:

```
SELECT 
  NAME as "User.Name",
  EMAIL as "User.Email.For.Criteria2.at." || ?
FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE 
  CRITERIA = ?
```

With some Java looping through all parameters with: (this is already in production)

```
ps.setString(i+1, parameterArray[i]);
```

I know I could build the query in Java, but my constraints are that deploying new Java code is to be avoided :/. I can modify the SQL though. Is this possible with Oracle SQL only?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column names (alias) are static in SQL and must be known at parse time (before binds). This allows some tools to know the number of columns, their names and their types before the query is executed.

Consequently, you can't name column aliases dynamically.

---

Another way to look at it: binds can only replace values. So ask yourself: could I replace the bind `?` by a constant expression for example `'A'`?

- you can replace the `?` in the where clause
- you can't replace the `?` in the column alias, this would produce a non-valid query.

Comment: Aw gosh, I thought only the database part limited this and not JDBC doing some early compilation :/

Comment: If my memory is correct, the query is sent to be parsed when you use [`Connection.prepareStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)), before any chance to set the bind values.